# Are there specialized strategies for those with slight math disabilities?

Tags: mathematical-psychology, mathematical-ability

I don't have very strong Dyscalculia, but I still have a generalized math disability, and despite receiving double-time to do quizzes and exams in my Calculus 1 course, I am still struggling to achieve the C grade I need to move onto Calc 2 which is required for my Computer Science major.

I want to improve at math and I am curious if there are specialized strategies people like me might benefit from.

I understand self-help questions are banned here, but judging by the response to the meta-site post regarding that. It seems like it might be allowable if the answers to the question can provide help to more than just the individual who posted the question.

Comment: You may wish to ask this over in https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: matheducators.stackexchange.com may also be of use (maybe even more than the standard math.se, I think that stack is mostly for asking questions about math rather than math learning). Math educators is tilted towards educators but does not exclude learners outright, and it seems like a question like this would be useful to both learners and teachers (and similar questions may already exist there - search those first).

Comment: A more specific description of the "generalized math disability" might be useful, too (unless that's already an accepted term - this isn't my area so apologies if I am ignorant), besides just ruling out dyscalculia. Maybe this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5803013/ would help classify where you fall?

Comment: I've decided to close this question after all.  I disagree with @BryanKrause that a more specific description would help this question, as I think it will just make it more self-help than it already is.  Some other options: Edit the question to remove personal references so that it is just a question on treatment/therapy for math learning disability, or try matheducators.SE as suggested - there is a [similar](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/11474), well-received question there.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I should clarify that I meant that suggestion for reframing the question to matheducators.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I apologize for the trouble. I will look around the Math Educators Stack Exchange website. I respect your decision and I appreciate your willingness as a moderator to explain your point of view here instead of simply closing it without an explanation. Thank you.